# SpriteKit: I'd need something like .pauseActionForKey()?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm a bit stuck at how to approach the following issue:

My scrolling game spawns obstacles of different kinds that are loaded from a plist. The spawning is delayed by an SKAction, the duration of which for each obstacle is computed by the y position.

**Updated** to reflect Wraithseeker's answer.

This is the setup code where all timers are started in the 
`didMoveToView()`:

```
for obstacleTuple in level.obstacleTuples {
  let positionY = obstacleTuple.positionY
  let obstacle = obstacleTuple.obstacle as! SKNode

  let duration = NSTimeInterval(positionY / kObstacleDistancePerSec)

  // **Update**: Instead of running the wait action on the scene...
  //runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(duration), completion: {
  // I should run it on the foregroundNode...
  foregroundNode.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(duration), completion: {
    self.foregroundNode.addChild(obstacle)
  })
}


// And then toggle the pause property on that node to stop and resume.
let foregroundNode.paused = foregroundNode.paused == true ? false : true
```

I'd like to have special events (which occur depending on user action), during which the spawning of above obstacles is further delayed and the player can collect bonus objects.
So basically, I'd need to assign a key to the wait SKAction and then have a `.pauseActionForKey()` method (instead of `.removeActionForKey()`).

Is it possible to extend `SKAction` with that?
Are there better ways to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you asking how to pause a node and it's current actions?

Comment: No, using the pause property doesn't help here, since the wait action continues running. Thinking about it, maybe I should run the wait SKAction on the obstacles instead of the scene. But even then, can I use the pause property on a node that isn't added yet? I'll try asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this will be to create an empty `SKNode` and assign those action to that node which you want to be paused. This is so that when you pause the actions, it does not pause your whole game since you are assigning the `SKActions` to the scene at the moment using `self`.

To pause the actions, simply call pause upon your empty `SKNode` as suggested by sangony.

An example

```
myEmptyNode.pause() //
```

Comment: Thanks Wraithseeker, I should've run the wait action on the foregroundNode and pause that node to achieve what I want. I've updated the code.